# Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() fiel Why return null?

Tags: java, android-studio, file, null

I'm trying to get the music(mp3,wav) file name of an Android Device, but the

```java
ArrayList<File> mySongs=findSong(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory());
```

field returns `null`.
Any ideas?

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>
```

```java
    public ArrayList<File> findSong(File file){
        ArrayList<File>arrayList=new ArrayList<>();
        File[] files= file.listFiles();

        for(File singleFile: files){
            if(singleFile.isDirectory()&&!singleFile.isHidden()){
                arrayList.addAll(findSong(singleFile));
            }
            else{
                if(singleFile.getName().endsWith(".mp3")||singleFile.getName().endsWith(".wav")){
                    arrayList.add(singleFile);
                }
            }
        }
        return arrayList;
    }


  void displaySongs(){
        final ArrayList<File> mySongs=findSong(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory());

        items=new String[mySongs.size()];
        for(int i=0;i<mySongs.size();i++){
            items[i]=mySongs.get(i).getName().toString().replace(".mp4","").replace(".wav","");
        }

        customAdapter customAdapter=new customAdapter();
        listView.setAdapter(customAdapter);
    }
```

Comment: Hi have you granted permission to read external storage? https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment#getExternalStorageDirectory()

Answer (score 0):

If you are calling `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` in field initialization, then you are likely making this call before your application is 'starting'. You should try assigning this field within the `onCreate()` method in your `Application` class ([docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application#onCreate())) as follows:

```java
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    this.mySongs = findSong(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory());
}
```